Package Error while running the python file | Tensorflow
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tf2: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

I find the above Error in package. I don't understand why is error happening. everything is correct anyone can fix above error in Library like Tensorflow etc..
I'm running this code in vs-code.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Try the below code.
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow==2.12.0 --upgrade


again facing same issue
